# Авторизация через Facebook на PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Пишу авторизацию через fb средствами php, сначала создаю ссылку для запроса, в ответ на нее получаю токен
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';

```
$params = array(
    'client_id'     => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope'         => 'email,user_birthday'
);

echo $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
```

Здесь все в порядке, пользователю выходит запрос на авторизацию пользователи в ответ прилетает код авторизации.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
   $params = array(
      'client_id' => $client_id,
      'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
      'client_secret' => $client_secret,
      'code' => $_GET['code']
   );
   $tokenInfo = null;
   $query = http_build_query($params);
   $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?$query";

   $data = file_get_contents($url);
   parse_str($data,$tokenInfo);

   $params = array('access_token' => $tokenInfo['access_token']);
   $query = urldecode(http_build_query($params));
   $request =   "https://graph.facebook.com/me?".urldecode(http_build_query($params));
   file_get_contents($request, true);
}
```

И тут уже при запросе file_get_contents вылетает ошибка

Error : file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=*здесь номер токена*): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

При этом при вводе в адресную строку нормально выводится ответ от fb

Answer (score 1):

На фейсбуке в настройках приложения убери галочку "нативное приложение или приложение для ПК". Он считает что ты будешь обращаться к приложению на fb из приложения на ПК, а не с сайта. 
И запрос с токеном я делал через curl. Пиши если что.